# T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM error calling static method

Tags: php, static-methods

I have this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM, expecting T_VARIABLE in blog/wp-content/plugins/plugin/php/utils/cloud_data.php on line 98

```
static public function set_templates()
{
    static::fetch_templates(); // line 98
}

static private function fetch_templates($folder_identifier = '')
{
    // ..
}
```

Google says that **T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM** means **expecting**. So error means: expecting T_VARIABLE.

But why? `fetch_templates()` function initializes his parameter to `''`.

Comment: which version of PHP are you using? static keyword is php 5.3

Comment: PAAMAYIM is Hebrew for "twice" and NEKUDOTAYIM means "colon", so it's expecting  a variable and it got a double colon (namespace operator) instead.

Comment: [T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM](http://phpsadness.com/sad/1)

Comment: php 5.3+. double colon? :| well, it have double colon...

Comment: @NomikOS: in php 5.3+ it shouldn't throw such message

Comment: ok, I am understanding, indeed I have not this error, is my client, anyway is a problem have compatibility errors, so I must avoid static:: keyword! what a pity!

Comment: @NomikOS - if your client is on PHP 5.2, you should **strongly** recommend him to upgrade because support for PHP 5.2 was dropped ages ago. It's never good to have unsupported and obsolete versions of software in use on a production website. There have been a number of major security fixes in 5.3 which won't have been implemented in 5.2, so he is likely highly vulnerable to being hacked. (And of course, he's missing out on all the newer language features... but I guess he won't care about that)

Comment: @sdc At the most ask to my clients leave php4 and is enough. In this case is for a WP plugin to be sold by him, See? He will not accept a product so badly supported IRL. The best is wait until php6, only in that stage we will can strongly recommend php5.3+ Sad but true. 8) cheers...

Comment: @NomikOS - 5.3 has **already** been superceded by 5.4. 5.5 is planned for next year. **There is no PHP6 coming** -- all the features originally planned for PHP6 have been implemented in PHP5.3 or 5.4 (except some of the UTF8 work, which has been deferred indefinitely). PHP 5.2 was End Of Life in Jan 2011. If you are using it you are vulnerable to hacking.

Comment: @sdc `There is no PHP6 coming` :( More over: most of clients have share hosting. This is the case with this client of mine. You can't wait until their hosting provider upgrades all their servers! I know what you say. I am using php5.3+ but we develop for [non-geeks](http://www.geeksaresexy.net/2010/09/20/so-true-the-pain-of-watching-non-geeks-use-computers/)... Thanks for the update...

Comment: @NomikOS - don't be sad about no PHP6; the features are all there, just with a different name. I hear what you say about working with the customer, but at the same time you have a responsibility to tell your customer that he is vulnerable. (also, his web host has a responsibility to upgrade -- if they're knowingly using unsupported software for nearly two years then they are being neglegent and deserve to be sued when they get hacked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static::` was introduced in <strike>5.4</strike> 5.3, and likely you have older php

In your case you can replace it with

```
self::fetch_templates();
```

Comment: if you're using a version prior to 5.3, you'd be better off upgrading rather than working around it, given that PHP5.2 hasn't been supported for quite some time now.

Comment: @SDC: I'm using php 5.3+ for more than year and I've never used `static::` ;-)

Comment: @zerkms - my comment was more aimed at the OP than at you :)  `static::` can be useful, though I also can't think of the last time I needed it.

Comment: @SDC: yeah, I've just made a side note :-) PS: static methods are evil ;-P

Comment: Yes, we can live without static methods but thanks to them I have time to some beers the  weekends :)

Comment: No, static is needed for Late Static Binding. There are many uses for it in OOP.

Comment: @Kris: that depends. Static in all its representation makes your code tightly coupled. Personally I've never used LSB and cannot imagine case when I would find it useful

Comment: How does it make it tightly coupled? Static doesn't care if there is a subclass or not, but if there is a subclass, it will make sure it calls the function on the child class. I agree it isn't used often, but is useful. The one time I needed it was when I was extending an abstract database singleton class.

Comment: @Kris: why did you prefer static call over regular "dynamic" call?

Comment: Because that is what a singleton is. It was a DB helper class that wouldnt have made as much sense as a non static class